# How to create algebraic structures in code

Tags: mathematical-programming

I've been searching around google and this site and I haven't been able to find the answer to this. How are algebraic structures (like a set and its elements, groups, rings, etc.) defined in code (in any language)? Like, if I wanted to "do things" with an arbitrary ring, how would I go about constructing that ring?

Comment: What would it mean for an algebraic structure to be defined in code?

Comment: Computer algebra systems implement algebraic structures "in code". Sage is open source, so you can take a look at how they are implemented there.

Comment: On top of Yuval's suggestion, I would also look at Haskell's constructive algebra library (https://github.com/iblech/constructive-algebra) and theorem prover languages such as Coq (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/ring.html) and Lean.